# Creating an animation of an app's screenshots?

Tags: iphone, animation

I am creating a how-to animation of an iphone app. I have got all the screenshots of the app. Wondering what the best tool is to create a short video/animation of these jpgs in your opinion?

Comment: Better ask this question in superuser.com as it is not a programming related question.

Comment: Thanks- I wondered if there was a specific one for such questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, if you go to my site where i've showcased my app, you can see the full source code there - it was just a simple jQuery slideshow inside an iPhone 4 png :)

http://www.twostepmedia.co.uk/apps.php

Answer (score 0):

Please update the post with the source code as the link no longer works.

Essentially, it's like benhowdle89 said. You can take any jQuery slideshow, adjust the image dimensions to the area inside your iPhone 4 .png, and you're pretty much done.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder...will have to dig for the source. Don't expect to update the answer any time soon